# Cannot auto select values in EasyAdmin using Elao Enum Types for select drop down

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony5, easyadmin

I have created an easy admin application, this is the code for the problem field:

```
 - { property: type, type: 'Elao\Enum\Bridge\Symfony\Form\Type\EnumType', type_options: {
 enum_class: 'App\Entity\Enum\PatientMessageTypeEnum', required: true,
 }, label: 'Type', help: 'Select type from the drop down above'}
```

So the issue is that on edit, the above is not automatically selected, it just selects the first value, always, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks correct. It is probably some other part of your config that is causing this behavior. The following works for us:

Make sure to define your doctrine types in elao_enum.yaml:

```
elao_enum:
  doctrine:
    types:
      App\Entity\Enum\LanguageEnum: language
```

Make sure the property in your entity is configured correctly, including the argument and return types of your getters and setters

```
/**
 * @var LanguageEnum
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="language", length=10)
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * @return LanguageEnum
 */
public function getLanguage(): LanguageEnum
{
  return $this->language;
}

/**
 * @param LanguageEnum $language
 */
public function setLanguage(LanguageEnum $language)
{
  $this->language = $language;
}
```

In EasyAdmin2 set the field type to the FQCN to the EnumType and configure it appropriately in the form section. To ensure the listing is working, set the type to text.

```
form: 
  fields:
    - { property: language, type: 'Elao\Enum\Bridge\Symfony\Form\Type\EnumType', type_options: { enum_class: 'App\Entity\Enum\LanguageEnum', required: true, }, label: 'Language', help: 'Select language from the drop down above'}

list:
  fields:
    - { property: language, label: 'Language', type: 'text'}
```

In EasyAdmin3, instead of using the ChoiceField, use a TextField and configure it to use the EnumType

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
  return [TextField::new('answerType')->
      setFormType(EnumType::class)->
      setFormTypeOptions(['enum_class' => AnswerTypeEnum::class])
  ];
}
```